# show expire date on rendered page, template code

Tags: templates, date

This should be a simple one. I just want o show the the date a channel entry is set to expire on a rendered page as well as when it was made. The Entry is straight forward enough but I can't seem to find a way to show the end date?

Thanks for looking!

```
{end_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but not quite.

```
{expiration_date format="%F %j, %Y"}
```

[Docs.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#expiration-date)